# DocuSign get Pem file

Tags: docusignapi, digital-signature, electronic-signature

I'm using DocuSign to sign my documents. I need the .pem file but I don't know where to find it. When I sign a document and download it I only get the signed document and a summary document. Where can I find the .pem file? Does each document I sign have a different .pem or the same .pem is used in each of my documents?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please ***check (accept)*** the best answer to your question. ***Thank you!***

Answer (score 2):

The general DocuSign product enables you to sign documents using Simple Electronic Signatures. Signer certificates, such as pem files, are only used for Advanced (AES) and Qualified Electronic Signatures (QES).

DocuSign supports AES and QES signatures too. Depending on what you want to do, either DocuSign can create the certificate for you, or you can supply your own certificate, or a Trust Service Provider can create the certificate for you.

Re:

> Where can I find the .pem file?

If DocuSign created the certificate for you then the private key is not available. The public certificate is included with the signed document.

> Does each document I sign have a different .pem or the same .pem is used in each of my documents?

If you use DocuSign's SES service, then you do not have a certificate. DocuSign will also sign any downloaded documents with an AES signature. This DocuSign signature guarantees the SES signatures. This signature is not specific to a signer.

If you sign with AES or QES then whether the same certificate is used for multiple signatures or not depends on the certificate source. In some cases a cert is reused, in others new certs are created as needed.

Answer (score 1):

PEM is the format of your private/public key. You can generate RSA key pair through you integrator key settings. The private key is used to sign the assertion during the JWT authentication flow. It is generated only once and you need to keep it in a secret place. The private or the public key can not be downloaded through the API.
Pem/private key is used during the authentication not envelope signing